# How many possible games of modified Blackjack?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

Assuming we are playing a modified version of Blackjack with the following rules, how many possible games are there?

1. 1 deck of 52 cards (4 suits of A-K) with normal hand total rules (A: 1 or 11, face cards are 10).
2. Player can only hit or stand, and dealer stops hitting once their hand total is greater than or equal to 17.

Comment: You need to show what you try.  What is your rule about the Ace, is it standard rule ? You need to split this very complex question to many more simple questions : First question : for each value $n$ between 2 and 21, how many hands with 2 cards give the total $n$

Comment: Also, not sure it is well defined.  The player's possible games depend on strategy (people seldom hit a $19$, say).  Are you ignoring that and just assuming that the player might play on regardless of common sense?  Conversely, are you counting games in which the player stands on a total of $5$ or whatever?  Are you allowing the player to split duplicates?